# posting through json and jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I'm totally new to JSON format so this is probably a very generic question and I'm not even sure this is the right way to go.

What I would like to do is write a JSON file with some text in it, something like a list of conversations.

```
var conversations = [
    one [{
        "you":"Hello",
        "him":"Hey there"
        }],
    two [{
        "you":"Hello on this second one",
        "him":"Hey there how are you"
    }]
];
```

then, on pageload, load a random conversation on my php index (I can use jquery). What's important for me is sending the `you`/`me` content to some specific divs.

the use case would be: Page loads, picks randomly conversation `one` and renders this on my page

```
<div class="you">Hello</div>
<div class="him">Hey there</div>
```

Am I in any way in the good direction? any suggestions or resources I can study to have something like this working? Any hint or `code` is greatly appreciated :) thanks

Comment: Your example would be a javascript file, not a file containing json. But to store data I would recommend a database instead of a json / text / javascript file. And you can do what you want to do both server-side (php) and client side (js / jQuery).

Comment: @jeroen thanks! It's actually a small project i don't need something that complicated. a javascript file would suit better? How would do that?

Comment: Sorry, but there are a lot of reasons to close this question (too broad, opinion based, asking for off-site resources...). You should give it a try and post back here when you run into a specific problem.

Comment: storing and retrieving from database will be less complex than writing dynamic file

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you're looking for?

```
<div id="you"></div>
<div id="him"></div>

<script>
    var conversations = [
        {
            you:"Hello",
            him:"Hey there"
        },
        {
            you:"Hello on this second one",
            him:"Hey there how are you"
        }
    ];

    // random number from 0 to 1
    var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) );

    var you = document.getElementById('you');
    var him = document.getElementById('him');

    you.innerHTML = conversations[random]['you'];
    him.innerHTML = conversations[random]['him'];
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vjdkLcvq/

Answer (score 0):

I am agree with you. I always prefer JSON instead of Database. Specially for a conversation project like yours. More readable, easy to edit etc.

here is the json file where I save text conversations.

messages.json

```
{
"1442831655": {
    "writtenFrom": "tom",
    "line1": "tom writing to jim."
}
```

action.php

```
$fileName = "./data/messages.json";
    $str_data = file_get_contents($fileName);
    $data = json_decode($str_data,true);

    echo json_encode( $data );
```

index.php

```
    ...<script src="../public/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="ad.js"></script>...
```

ads.js

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

showInbox(authUser);

});
```

Just sending you some ideas. The whole script is much more complex. (PHP, AJAX, JSON)